# Boundedness of solution to a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ is a convex function with the property that level sets of $f$ are compact. I know that any solution of the differential equation $$\dot{x}=-\nabla f(x)$$ is bounded because $(d/dt) f(x) = - ||\nabla f(x)||^2$ so that $x_t$ always stays within the level set $\{ u ~| f(u) \leq f(x_0)\}$.

My question is: suppose I have instead $$m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} = - \nabla f(x),$$ where $m > 0$ and $c \geq 0$. It seems natural to guess that this will stay bounded as well. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the [Hamiltonian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Basic_physical_interpretation):
$$
H(x, \dot{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\,m\, {|\dot{x}|}^2 \;+\; f(x)\, .
$$

Then:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}H(x, \dot{x})
&= m\, \dot{x}\cdot\ddot{x} \;+\; \dot{x}\cdot\nabla f(x)\\[0.05in]
&= \dot{x}\cdot\left[m\, \ddot{x} \;+\; \nabla f(x)\right]\\[0.05in]
&=\dot{x}\cdot\left[-c\,\dot{x} \;-\; \nabla f(x)\;+\; \nabla f(x)\right]\\[0.05in]
&= -c\, {|\dot{x}|}^2
\end{align}
Thus $x(t)$ is bounded in the same sense as in your original example, except with $H$ in place of $f$.